# tomcat memory issue

Tags: jsp, memory, tomcat

I am having more than 150 web applications in my tomcat web-apps directory can these be the one of the reason for increase in memory usage. i have installed tomcat as a service .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certainly. It has got to store the data *somewhere*. The memory is the best and fastest place to do that. Every created object instance/primitive value in Java code will be stored in memory.

If you have problems with it, then either increase the available memory for Tomcat or [profile](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) the webapp's code and fix memory leaks/inefficiencies accordingly. You can also consider storing large and more permanent data in a relational database instead and load *only* the relevant data on a HTTP request basis.

---

**Update**: If you're using Netbeans, you can use the builtin profiler to profile the webapp during development: http://profiler.netbeans.org. Further you can use [VisualM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) to independently profile Tomcat. [Here's a nice blog](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/monitoring-tomcat-with-java-visualvm) which outlines how to do that. You can stresstest webapplications using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

Comment: but I am using only one application rest of them(149) are just the back up of the one, is these causes memory issues

Comment: A deployed webapp certainly costs memory, but if the webapp isn't been used, never accessed (also not by bots) and does in fact *nothing* in the background, then it shouldn't *increasingly* cost memory. If that is the case, then likely the main webapp is leaking memory. As said, run a profiler to spot the leak/inefficiency in the code.

Comment: i need some profiler right , can you tell which profiler is the best to monitor memory leak also it should have a option of monitoring the tomcat via remote machine(i mean some other machine), i have already goggled regarding this unable to find any.